# codepipeline for lambda not deploying the latest code

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have created a pipeline to deploy lambda code. This is what my template looks like

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template 

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

This is the buildspec

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
  build:
    commands:
      - export BUCKET=codepipeline-bucket
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml --s3-bucket $BUCKET  --output-template-file outputtemplate.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template.yml
    - outputtemplate.yml
```

Everytime I push to github and do a pull request and merge to master, the source step gets triggered. The build gets triggered followed by deploy. All steps finish successfully. The problem I am having is the code deployed is always N-1 version behind.
If I need to make any deployments get the latest code then I have to click the Release Change button on the pipeline application. By just checking in code and merging the pull request, it doesn't get the latest code, but only the commit I merged previously. I don't know where to look next to solve this problem. Its almost as if the very last commit in my code under the src folder is not detected when its merged in, but the previous commit is.